# How can I compile in xcode to two clients with one code (parametrize information flutter app)

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I have one code typed to one client. Now I wanna re-use the same code and adapt it to another client. How can I compile the same app for two bundles for example (changing its unique things like icons, bundle, version, and features?

Comment: First you should describe what are differences between those two clients. I guess that respective entry in plist file should do the job.

Comment: I have to change the background images and icons. The first app is more complete, this new will have only two 'menus'

Comment: Respective entry?